# set text for google+ link with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, google-plus, sharing

I want to open a google share dialog with some data, I use this as of now:

```
var GOOGLE_BASE_URL = "https://plus.google.com/share?url=";
url += GOOGLE_BASE_URL + urlToShare;
window.open(url, null, DIMENSIONS);
```

How can I set the text that will be the inserted into the comment section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to prefill the text of a share is to use [Interactive Posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) in place of the share link.  This a feature that comes with [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in/).  It may not be the best solution for you if you are trying for a general share approach.  However, if you are using Google as an authentication method already, then Google+ Sign-In could be a good option for you.  Interactive Posts not only allow you to prefill text, but also to prefill up to 10 recipients of the share, who will all be directly notified of the share.

Comment: thank you, I already looked into it and seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/):

> The Google+ share endpoint accepts the following query parameters:
>
> ```
> Parameter   Description
> url         The URL of the page to share. This value should be url encoded.
> hl          The language code for the locale to use on the Google+ sharing page.
> ```

Google provide no way for a page author to specify the comment that the user should make about the link.

So, you can't.

Comment: damn I knew about it, but I hoped I missed something, thanks for confirming it for me.